# How to read a DNS SOA record?

Tags: dns

I'm having some trouble reading SOA records. I get the following response after using `dig` to fetch the SOA record of a domain I'm in control of.

```
SOA ns1.example.com. xxx.gmail.com. 2013041357 14400 14400 1209600 86400
```

How am I supposed to know which value is associated with each field? According to [this article](http://www.zytrax.com/books/dns/ch8/soa.html) a SOA record can have nine fields.

I am imagining that each space signifies the end of a value and I can see that the second value is the email address. But how would I determine which is the refresh value and which is the retry value? They're just numbers with no field names next to them!

Am I missing something here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks to everyone who helped. I've worked out where I was going wrong. Good old Stack Overflow!

Comment: The link to the article you posted is down.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

If you use `+multiline` dig parameter, you'll see a more verbose output.

```
dig SOA +multiline yahoo.com

yahoo.com.      1800 IN SOA ns1.yahoo.com. hostmaster.yahoo-inc.com. (
                2013041300 ; serial
                3600       ; refresh (1 hour)
                300        ; retry (5 minutes)
                1814400    ; expire (3 weeks)
                600        ; minimum (10 minutes)
                )
```

Comment: Perfect. By using this in conjunction with the information in the answer below everything makes sense.

Answer (score 5):

See [this link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/163971).

As shown:

```
@   IN  SOA     nameserver.place.dom.  postmaster.place.dom. (
          1      ; serial number
       3600      ; refresh   [1h]
        600      ; retry     [10m]
      86400      ; expire    [1d]
       3600 )    ; min TTL   [1h]
```

Comment: That link is down.

Comment: Well that's unfortunate - it's a Microsoft support document :(